# React Router only one link working Github Pages

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-router, github-pages

For some reason only one of my links are working with react router and github pages. The home page and index page load fine but the links to the inspect page and the sandbox page return 404 errors when on github pages. It all works locally so I am not sure why index is working on github pages but inspect and sandbox are not (also the background image is stored in /public and works fine both locally and on github pages). So http://user.github.io/my-app/ works and  http://user.github.io/my-app/index works but not  http://user.github.io/my-app/inspect and  http://user.github.io/my-app/sandbox . The result is the same whether or not I use the buttons on the home page or type the links manually. I've also tried removing `{process.env.PUBLIC_URL+` from the links but then it links to http://user.github.io/index or whatever it says it links to so that does not work. Another thing I tired was having all the links load the Index component to see if it was a component issue but that did not change anything. Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is my App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Inspect from './components/Inspect'
import Index from './components/Index'
import Sandbox from './components/Sandbox'

declare global {
    interface Window {
        $pop:any;
    }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Home />} />
          <Route path="/index" exact component={() => <Index />} />
          <Route path="/inspect" exact component={() => <Inspect />} />
          <Route path="/sandbox" exact component={() => <Sandbox />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my Home.tsx with the button links to the other pages:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Home" style={{ textAlign:"center" }}>
            <img src= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/background.png'} alt="logo" />
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div id="custom">
                <form action={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/index"}>
                  <input type="submit" className="home-button" value="Index" />
              </form>
              <br />
              <form action={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/inspect"}>
                <input type="submit" className="home-button" value="Inspect" />
            </form>
            <br />
            <form action={process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/sandbox"}>
                  <input type="submit" className="home-button" value="Sandbox" />
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Homepage in package.json:

```
"homepage": "http://user.github.io/my-app",
```

Comment: You should not use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` for this. Instead, define a constant for yourself and assign it '/my-app', then use it wherever you are using `PUBLIC_URL` in router / forms. Also, not sure why you are using forms instead of regular links. Additionally, instead of a constant for _basename_, you can try extracting the `"homepage"` value directly from _package.json_ at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Leandro comment worked! Changed the forms to links and changed `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to (for now hard coded but will change to a const global var ) `"/my-app"`. Here's the updated code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Home.css';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Home" style={{ textAlign:"center" }}>
            <img src= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/background.png'} alt="logo" />
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div id="custom">
                <Link to="/index">
                  <input type="submit" className="home-button" value="Index" />
              </Link>
              <br /><br />
              <Link to="/inspect">
                <input type="submit" className="home-button" value="Inspect" />
            </Link>
            <br /><br />
            <Link to="/sandbox">
                  <input type="submit" className="home-button" value="Sandbox" />
              </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Inspect from './components/Inspect'
import Index from './components/Index'
import Sandbox from './components/Sandbox'

declare global {
    interface Window {
        $pop:any;
    }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router basename="/my-app">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={() => <Home />} />
          <Route path="/index" exact component={() => <Index />} />
          <Route path="/inspect" exact component={() => <Inspect />} />
          <Route path="/sandbox" exact component={() => <Sandbox />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```